# Faster than double for loop on Counter object

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, counter

I want to do a double loop on a Counter object, which is the result of two different counters subtraction.
My counter is like this:

```
{'sun': 5,
 'abstract': 0.0,
 'action': 10,
 'ad': 0.0,
  ....}
```

And I have a dataframe like:

```
    0           1   
0   sun         sunlight        
2   river       water   
3   stair       staircase
4   morning     sunrise 
n   ......
```

My purpose is to to keep in the dataframe only couples of words which the first word of the row have 0 of frequency and the second more than 0 (or the contrary, more than zero the first and 0 the second, so excluding couples both of 0 frequency or both of more than zero frequency).

I've tried to do this, but it is too slow (it will take more than 5 hours to complete):

```
for i,j in counter_diff.items():       #extract i word and j counter number of a item
  for t,k in counter_diff.items():     #extract t word and k counter number of a item
    for s in range(len(df)):
      if ((df[0][s] == i and j==0) and (df[1][s] == t and k==0)):
        df = df.drop([s])
      elif ((df[0][s] == i and j>0) and (df[1][s] == t and k>0)):
        df = df.drop([s])
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Have you any suggestion of a better way to do it?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why are you iterating over the counter to begin with?

Comment: To check for words in the counter that match words in the dataframe. The counter was created on a different list of words.

Comment: How does the `Counter` object get elements with a zero count?

Comment: @Radix that defeats the whole point. A counter is a `dict`. You just *access the keys in the dict directly*. Don't iterate over the dict.

Comment: Make two extra columns in your dataframe that map the values from the dict. Then use vectorized operations to filter the rows based on those columns

Comment: @Barmar I forgot to mention that my Counter object is a difference of two other counters, so if those two counters have the same number on a word, it can be 0 or even a negative number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) + [`numpy.logical_xor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# toy Counter object
counts = Counter({'sun': 5, 'abstract': 0, 'action': 10, 'ad': 0})

# toy DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["sun", "sunlight"],
        ["river", "water"],
        ["stair", "staircase"],
        ["morning", "sunrise"]])

# map the counts element-wise over all the elements of the DataFrame
# and create boolean mask
indicators = df.applymap(lambda x: counts.get(x, 0)) > 0

# use a logical xor to find the combinations where the count is 0 and >0 (and the other way around)
mask = np.logical_xor(indicators[0], indicators[1])

# finally filter using a mask
res = df[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
     0         1
0  sun  sunlight
```

The time complexity of this approach is `O(n)` where n is the size (number of cells) of the DataFrame. More info in xor (exclusive or) can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Comment: Thanks! What if I have negative values in my counter (I forgot to mention that my Counter object is a difference of two other counters) ?

Comment: So use `!=` instead of `>` ? What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: Right, sorry for the stupid question :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
d = {'sun': 5, 'abstract': 0.0, 'action': 10, 'ad': 0.0}
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ["sun", "river", "stair", "morning"], 
                   1: ["sunlight", "water", "staircase", "sunrise"]})

>>> df.loc[(df[0].map(d)>0)+(df[1].map(d)>0)==1]
     0         1
0  sun  sunlight
```

If you have other columns in `df` and want to check if exactly one column has a count greater than 0:

```
>>> df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x.map(d)>0).sum(axis=1)==1]
```